# POW Doesn't serve Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack-pow

When I run the project form rails server, it works fine, when I open it in POW with http://mon.dev/rails/info/properties, I get this:

```
Error: Response was not received
Error: Response was not received
    at Client._finishRequest (/Users/hb/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.3.2/node_modules/nack/lib/client.js:75:27)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/hb/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.3.2/node_modules/nack/lib/client.js:37:21)
    at Client.emit (events.js:81:20)
    at Array.0 (net.js:831:12)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
```

I've been struggling to install ror for a while now. I've setup Rails 3.2.0 and Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM, and set 'rvm use 1.9.3 --default', I have created the .rvmc file in the project dirctory.

Comment: What version of RVM are you running? Try updating it (`rvm get head`) and see if that helps.

Comment: Latest. A fresh install, a couple of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like something is wrong with Pow. Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling it?

You might also try creating a gemset for this project:

```
rvm use 1.9.3
rvm gemset create mon
```

Then install Rails, `bundle install`, etc. That would lessen the possibility of gem conflicts.